# Is $L^{\infty}(Z)$ first-countable?

Tags: functional-analysis

Is $L^{\infty}(Z)$  first-countable? A space X is said to be first-countable if each point has a countable neighbourhood basis (local base). $L^{\infty}(Z)$ is dual of $L^{1}(Z)$ with  convolution multiplication.

Comment: Which topology do you consider? In the norm topology, the space is metrisable, hence first countable.

Comment: With weak star topology .

Comment: In that case, note that the weak$^\ast$ topology on the dual of an infinite-dimensional Banach space is never first countable, since an infinite-dimensional Banach space has uncountable dimension. However, if $E$ is a separable Banach space, then the closed unit ball of its dual is metrisable in the subspace topology induced by the weak$^\ast$ topology.

Comment: Thank you for your kindness